# Fetching data from array based on the value and content of inner array - ReactJS

Tags: arrays, reactjs

The data that i recieve looks like this :

```
const myArray = [{
    reason: 'vacation'
    list: [{
        name: 'John Doe'
        startsAt: '2022-05-19'
        endsAt: '2022-06-01'

      },
      {
        name: 'Jenifer Doe'
        startsAt: '2022-06-10'
        endsAt: '2022-06-15'
      }
    ],
  },
  {
    reason: 'sick'
    list: [{
      name: 'Susan'
      startsAt: '2022-05-20'
      endsAt: '2022-05-21'
    }]
  }
]
```

The final result that i want to achieve is an table with that will look something like this :

```
=====================================================
| Name        | Created at | Canceled at |  Reason  |
=====================================================
| John Doe    | 2022-05-19 | 2022-06-01  | vacation |
-----------------------------------------------------
| Jenifer Doe | 2022-06-10 | 2022-06-15  | vacation |
-----------------------------------------------------
| Susan       | 2022-05-20 | 2022-05-21  | sick     |
```

This is my try to get the data that i need into my table

```
export const MyComponent: FunctionComponent = () => {
    return (
        <>
            {myArray.map((data) => (
                <tr>
                    <td>{data.reason}</td>
                    data.list.map((listData) => {
                         <td>{listData.name}</td>
                         <td>{listData.startsAt}</td>
                         <td>{listData.endsAt}</td>
                     })
                </tr>
            ))}
        </>
    )
}
```

I think that map in map is not the solution here . Can someone give me a hand and explain me what is going on ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, since it appears that you want each row in the table to be the elements in each `list` property, you might consider flattening those arrays into a single array. Ideally, you want to get it into a format that more closely resembles the rows of the table, for example:

```
const myNewArray = [
  {
    name: "John Doe",
    startsAt: "2022-05-19",
    endsAt: "2022-06-01",
    reason: "vacation",
  },
  {
    name: "Jenifer Doe",
    startsAt: "2022-06-10",
    endsAt: "2022-06-15",
    reason: "vacation",
  },
  {
    name: "Susan",
    startsAt: "2022-05-20",
    endsAt: "2022-05-21",
    reason: "sick",
  },
];
```

This can be achieved, for example, by using [Array.prototype.reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)
:

```
const myNewArray = myArray.reduce((newArray, item) => {
    const reason = item.reason;
    newArray = newArray.concat(
      item.list.map((listItem) => ({ ...listItem, reason }))
    );
    return newArray;
  }, []);
```

Then you can render the rows of the table using a single map:

```
<>
  {myNewArray.map((data) => (
    <tr>
      <td>{data.name}</td>
      <td>{data.startsAt}</td>
      <td>{data.endsAt}</td>
      <td>{data.reason}</td>
    </tr>
  ))}
</>
```